# cookie value not set in first time in angular js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cookies, mean-stack

I want to get cookie value from one UI to another page.

That cookie value is user name.
EX:Nithya

When i logged to the home page the cookie value is empty the cookie value is set set after refreshing a page.

I want to set the cookie value when the load is load.

this is my home page Controller code

```
app.controller('homeCtrl',
    function ($scope, $http, $window, $filter, $cookieStore) {
         var logincheck = function () {
            $http.get('loggedin').success(function (user) {
                console.log(user);
                $cookieStore.put('LoggedinUser', user);
                $scope.LoggedinUsers = $cookieStore.get('LoggedinUser');

            });
        };
        logincheck();

    });
```

i am using the cookie in this code.

```
app.controller('RoleViewCtrlq', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', '$filter', '$cookieStore', '$notify', '$timeout',
function ($scope, $http, $window, $filter, $cookieStore, $notify, $timeout)
{



    var username = $cookieStore.get('LoggedinUser');
}]);
```

can anyone give the solution..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`$cookiesStore` is deprecated since v1.4.0 use `$cookies` instead

```
        $cookies.put('LoggedinUser', user);
       var username = $cookie.get('LoggedinUser');
```

And you should use `then` instead `success` . `success` and `error` deprecated too

Comment: I am using moongoose if i use succes means values are not fetch from server.js